# HTML - How to scrape not visible elements using python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to scrape a webpages.
I am trying to scrape data from this https://painel-covid19.saude.ma.gov.br/vacinas. But the problem is I am getting the tags in outputs empty. In the Inspect Element I can see the data, but in page source not. You can see the code is hidden in . How can I retrieve it using python? Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't "not visible".  The issue is that the data is being filled in by Javascript code.  You won't see the data unless you are executing the Javascript on the page.  You can do that with the `selenium` package, which runs a copy of Chrome to do the rendering.